# index.ts:105 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _firebase_util__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.getModularInstance)(...).onAuthStateChanged is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

when i am trying to go to my privet route show this error of firebase and my website crushed

this is error below :

````
    at onAuthStateChanged (index.ts:105:1)
    at index.esm.js:127:1
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23049:1)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24816:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24781:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24768:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24756:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:26990:1)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26935:1)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26886:1)```
````

Comment: Can you edit and update your question with your code and also include your Firebase version ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.